# What are these things?

Tags: modeling

Can someone tell me what these weird red textures are that's just floating above my object? I can't select them and they are not in my collect list.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look like annotations or similar which may have been made with the grease pencil.[image]

If you select the annotation menu you can find the eraser mode.

Comment: Thank you they were annotations!